# How to do multi group by and output to CSV

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple 'Action' table I use to record user actions that looks like this:

```
{
  label (varchar),
  timestamp
}
```

A record is saved for every action a user completes.

I now need to output a report that looks something like this:

```
Date, Label1Count, Label2Count, Label3Count, ... 
dd/mm/yy, 34, 44, 55, ...
dd/mm/yy, 34, 44, 55, ...
dd/mm/yy, 34, 44, 55, ...
```

Where Date is the day the action took place, and each label header is one of the labels that I record.

I can output something similar no probs:

```
label, date, count
label, date, count
...
```

And order it so that labels are grouped together and then dates.

I would then need to copy and paste it in Excel to match the desired view.

Any ideas how I would get the first view using pure SQL? I could do it with a combo of python and SQL, but I'm sure SQL alone could do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) in PostGreSQL, but I don't like it.

So I use this pattern instead...

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)           AS label_x_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)           AS label_y_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)           AS label_z_count
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  timestamp
```

Obviously, this only works when you know all the labels that you are pivotting.

If you don't knw all the labels, and you want a result set with a dynamic number of columns, you need dynamic SQL *(code that writes SQL, specifically the new lines of code for the different labels)*.  There isn't a single static query that can do that for you.

Because you need dynamic SQL when you don't know the different label values at design time, the normalised data-set is often actually the best methodology in your data layer.  Your client code could then transform that normalised data set into flat file dataset in a model layer.  Or similar.

For this reason, I often recommend not pivotting the data in a SQL environment.

Comment: ok - I don't know the labels beforehand, so will have to do this Python instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is table pivoting. It is not easy to achieve with pure sql. However if number of cases of label are fixed you may succeed in SELECT CASE WHEN statement. If types of labels are not fixed you should go for something else. Only some sql engines do not have solution for this.
Have a look at this: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html